# Enabling exactly once causes streams shutdown due to timeout while initializing transactional state

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I've written a simple example to test the join functionality. As I sometimes get messages duplicated in the resulting topic and sometimes missing messages in this topic, I thought while pinpointing the problem to enable exactly once semantics. However while doing this through:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

I get a timeout that causes kafka streams to shut down in my app:

```
2019-05-02 17:02:32.585  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2019-05-02 17:02:32.585  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2019-05-02 17:02:32.593  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1-0_0-producer, transactionalId=join-test-0_0] ProducerId set to -1 with epoch -1
2019-05-02 17:03:32.599 ERROR 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] Error caught during partition assignment, will abort the current process and re-throw at the end of rebalance: {}

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.

2019-05-02 17:03:32.599  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] partition assignment took 60044 ms.
    current active tasks: []
    current standby tasks: []
    previous active tasks: []

2019-05-02 17:03:32.601  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
2019-05-02 17:03:32.601  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
2019-05-02 17:03:32.615  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
2019-05-02 17:03:32.615  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72] State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR
2019-05-02 17:03:32.615  WARN 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
2019-05-02 17:03:32.615  INFO 153056 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [join-test-90a0aa93-dfd8-4d4f-894b-85a3c5634f72-StreamThread-1] Failed to rebalance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:870)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:810)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.
```

```
    static String ORIGINAL = "original-sensor-data";
    static String ERROR = "error-score";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SpringApplication.run(JoinTest.class, args);
        Properties props = getProperties();


        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KStream<String, OriginalSensorData> original = builder.stream(ORIGINAL, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new OriginalSensorDataSerde()));
        final KStream<String, ErrorScore> error = builder.stream(ERROR, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new ErrorScoreSerde()));



        KStream<String, ErrorScore> result = original.join(
                error,
                (originalValue, errorValue) -> new ErrorScore(new Date(originalValue.getTimestamp()), errorValue.getE(),
                        originalValue.getData().get("TE700PV").doubleValue(), errorValue.getT(), errorValue.getR()),
                // KStream-KStream joins are always windowed joins, hence we must provide a join window.
                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(3000).toMillis()),

                Joined.with(
                        Serdes.String(), /* key */
                        new OriginalSensorDataSerde(), /* left value */
                        new ErrorScoreSerde() /* right value */
                )
        ).through("atl-joined-data-repartition", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new ErrorScoreSerde()));

        result.foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Join Stream: " + key + " " + value));
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        streams.start();
    }

    private static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Url of the kafka broker, this can also be found in the Aiven console
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9095");
        props.put("group.id", "join-test");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put("application.id", "join-test");
        props.put("default.timestamp.extractor", "com.my.SensorDataTimestampExtractor");

        //The key of a message is a string
        props.put("key.deserializer",
                StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.deserializer",
                StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
        return props;
    }
```

I'm expecting that the app starts without the timeout and continues working

Comment: What is your question? Maybe you should just increase the timeout?

Comment: well my question is, why does enabling this exactly once property break not only my app, but also the kafka stream samples without any of my code in it? According to the docs it should be as easy as enabling this property.

Comment: Seem there is a configuration problem. Not sure atm. Did you inspect the logs (client and broker side) for more details why it times out? -- Also, you you mention "example application" -- EOS required 3 brokers by default: cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#processing-guarantee

Comment: ofcourse, 3 brokers, will check that. that might be it

Comment: @mmelsen did using 3 brokers help to resolve this?

Comment: @Mike I'm having the same issue when i stop one broker out of three. I was checking High Availability test scenarios. Shouldn't the streaming app still run if one out of three brokers is down (topic partition:3 and replication:3)